# Skip first and last point connecting in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to connect points of different colors in graph. But somehow it connect also first and last point I guess (when I am changing `'o'` to `'o-'`). I wen through several questions there, but did not find answer.

Initial plot:

[image: Only points]

What happened:

[image: Lines]

I was truing to connect first point to last to show the trajectory.

Code:

```
for k in range(0, n_clusters):
    x=[]
    y=[]
    for j in range(0, len(final_cluster_result[k])):
        x_res = list(final_cluster_result[k][j].longitude)
        y_res = list(final_cluster_result[k][j].latitude)
        x.append(x_res)
        y.append(y_res)
    x = [s for t in x for s in t]
    y = [s for t in y for s in t]
    plt.plot(x,y,'o',markersize=3)
    plt.grid(which='both')
    plt.title(f'Clustering {k}',fontsize=14)
    plt.xlabel("Longitude",fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel("Latitude",fontsize=15)
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Do you want the first and last point to be connected? Or do you *not* want that?

Comment: It shouldn’t be connecting the first and last point. It should just be connecting the dots in the order you define them in `x` and `y`. Are you sure it is connecting the first and last points?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that matplotlib does _not_ connect first and last point. But if your data is not sorted, these two points happen to be anywhere in the middle of your clusters, where you don't see that there is a gap in your line. So basically, without knowing what your `x` and `y` look like, it's hard to give a hint. You definitely should create a [mcve] together with a descrption of the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I cannot help you with `matplotlib` but I can propose another plotting library. Having experience with similar spatial data (I see you have latitude-longitude) I have found [`plotly's mapbox`](https://plot.ly/python/scattermapbox/) to be easy for creating interactive maps, where trajectories can easily be plotted.

If you are interested, here is some sample code to get you started. I left several (not necessarily needed) layout properties from an older project. The code outputs an html file you can open to access your interactive map from your browser.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.offline

df = #  dataframe with at least 'longitude','latitude','cluster' columns and 1 row for each point
your_color_list = # specify color for each cluster, using a colors list with length = n_clusters

# define the lines to be plotted
map_lines = []
for cluster, group in df.groupby('cluster'):  # group dataframe by cluster and iterate over the groups
    for i in range(len(group)): # iterate over each group (cluster) and plot the lines
        map_lines.append(
            go.Scattermapbox(
                lon=list(group['longitude']),
                lat=list(group['latitude']),
                mode='lines',
                line=go.scattermapbox.Line(
                    width=4,
                    color=your_color_list[i], 
                ),
            )
        )
# define the map's layout
map_layout = dict(
                autosize=True,
                showlegend=False,
                height=850,
                font=dict(color='#191A1A'),
                titlefont=dict(color='#191A1A', size=18),
                margin=dict(
                    l=25,
                    r=25,
                    b=25,
                    t=35
                ),
                hovermode='closest',
                plot_bgcolor='#fffcfc',
                paper_bgcolor='#fffcfc',
                legend=dict(font=dict(size=10), orientation='h'),
                title='Visualization of trajectories',
                mapbox=dict(
                    accesstoken = your_access_token, # get a free token from plotly site
                    style='outdoors',
                    center={'lon': 22,'lat': 40}, # define the coordinates of the center of your plot, now your map is over Greece
                    bearing=0,
                    zoom=14, # map zoom
                )
            )

fig = go.Figure(
    data=map_lines,
    layout=map_layout)

plotly.offline.plot(
    fig,
    filename='your_file_name_here.html')
```